# Regarding installation of utils.logger module

Tags: python

when i am trying to install that particular module  utils.logger ,it is showing
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement utils.logger (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for utils.logger.Sorry if my way of interpretation of question is not in an appropriate manner as i am a novice.
This is the code

import logging
import functools
import argparse
import os
from datetime import datetime
from utils.logger import setlogger

from utils.train_utils import train_utils

args = None

def parse_args():
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Train')

```
# basic parameters
parser.add_argument('--model_name', type=str, default='cnn_2d', help='the name of the model')
parser.add_argument('--data_name', type=str, default='CWRUSlice', help='the name of the data')
parser.add_argument('--data_dir', type=str, default= "E:\Data\西储大学轴承数据中心网站", help='the directory of the data')
parser.add_argument('--normlizetype', type=str, choices=['0-1', '1-1', 'mean-std'], default='0-1', help='data normalization methods')
parser.add_argument('--processing_type', type=str, choices=['R_A', 'R_NA', 'O_A'], default='R_A',
                    help='R_A: random split with data augmentation, R_NA: random split without data augmentation, O_A: order split with data augmentation')
parser.add_argument('--cuda_device', type=str, default='0', help='assign device')
parser.add_argument('--checkpoint_dir', type=str, default='./checkpoint', help='the directory to save the model')
parser.add_argument("--pretrained", type=bool, default=True, help='whether to load the pretrained model')
parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=64, help='batchsize of the training process')
parser.add_argument('--num_workers', type=int, default=0, help='the number of training process')

# optimization information
parser.add_argument('--opt', type=str, choices=['sgd', 'adam'], default='adam', help='the optimizer')
parser.add_argument('--lr', type=float, default=0.001, help='the initial learning rate')
parser.add_argument('--momentum', type=float, default=0.9, help='the momentum for sgd')
parser.add_argument('--weight_decay', type=float, default=1e-5, help='the weight decay')
parser.add_argument('--lr_scheduler', type=str, choices=['step', 'exp', 'stepLR', 'fix'], default='fix', help='the learning rate schedule')
parser.add_argument('--gamma', type=float, default=0.1, help='learning rate scheduler parameter for step and exp')
parser.add_argument('--steps', type=str, default='9', help='the learning rate decay for step and stepLR')


# save, load and display information
parser.add_argument('--max_epoch', type=int, default=100, help='max number of epoch')
parser.add_argument('--print_step', type=int, default=100, help='the interval of log training information')
args = parser.parse_args()
return args
```

if **name** == '**main**':

```
args = parse_args()
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = args.cuda_device.strip()
# Prepare the saving path for the model
sub_dir = args.model_name+'_'+args.data_name + '_' + datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%m%d-%H%M%S')
save_dir = os.path.join(args.checkpoint_dir, sub_dir)
if not os.path.exists(save_dir):
    os.makedirs(save_dir)

# set the logger
setlogger(os.path.join(save_dir, 'training.log'))

# save the args
for k, v in args.__dict__.items():
    logging.info("{}: {}".format(k, v))

trainer = train_utils(args, save_dir)
trainer.setup()
trainer.train()
```

Comment: Is the package you want named `python-utils`?

Comment: no sir , i have already installed utils module. nad this is the code, i have just posted the code and thanks